# Shell Script Test Data Output?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to find a way to generate a random quantity of numbers with a specific amount of numbers after too, for example 1000 which is 4 digits I know how to do this using:

```
   for i in {1..50}; do echo $((RANDOM%50+50)); done
```

which gives me an integer data type of 2 digits in length whereas what i'm looking for is something that can give me 200 in length but I don't want to be typing out 200 0's after the number

I want for example a question where I get asked 'How many digits would you like to randomly generate?' then I would input 200 and I would get 50 rows in this case of 200 digit numbers.

Cheers,

Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ numbers=50
$ digits=200
$ for ((i=0; i<${numbers}; i++)) ; do for ((j=0; j<${digits}; j++)) ; do echo -n $((RANDOM%10)); done ; echo ; done
```

**UPDATE**

Extending to random string generation:

```
$ numstrings=10
$ numchars=16
$ for((j=0; j<${numstrings}; j++)) ; do cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z' | fold -w ${numchars} | head -n 1 ; done
xCzgmBrAAuJBwzHw
eaBMxlpIbkAObhNa
GSYeEYPtlLbdLTFm
NVAacXEaVIRzewJU
YQzrXNXEpvNEaDjW
AoBjxTvnGYjeDAVO
hsJYoCTbqlKTfxKm
qbadlRTlztQxwCCb
XuvawFnxNfQrIaWX
QQyWqxZqUBQuCKQt
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Would you know how to do the same but randomly generated characters?

Comment: I would generate a random integer in the ASCII interval you are nterested to (for example just uppercase chars) and then replace echo -n with printf "%c" random_ascii_value...

Comment: Could you paste the code I would have to write to do that please?

Comment: So far I have got the following:

`WORDFILE="/usr/share/dict/words"
NUMWORDS=1
#Number of lines in $WORDFILE
tL=``awk 'NF!=0 {++c} END {print c}' $WORDFILE`
`for i in ``seq $NUMWORDS``
do
   rnum=$((RANDOM%$tL+1))
   sed -n "$rnum p" $WORDFILE
done
`
But i need to be able to specify the length of each word coming out. Ps. i don't know how to make it look like code...

Comment: This is the output I receive - `tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
Ptr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
Ftr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Are you on Unix/Linux? Do you have a file named /dev/urandom?

Comment: I'm on mac doing it through the Mac terminal, but yeah I do have that file.

Comment: Oh...OSX. Then export LC_ALL=C before running the command reading from /dev/urandom to avoid invalid UTF-8 sequences...

Comment: thank you I've put that in my script and its working fine :D

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted